# Scrolling issue in table view

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have UITableView i am displaying table view with custom cell.

My issue is when i scroll table view the cells is creating again and again.

Help me to solve this.

Thanks.

//cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
 -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:  (NSIndexPath *)indexPath 

{

 ListOfProductsCell *cell =(ListOfProductsCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"tableCell"];

if (cell==nil) {

        NSArray *nib =[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ListOfProductsCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = (ListOfProductsCell *)[nib objectAtIndex:0];

}

if (tableView == self.searchDisplayProduct.searchResultsTableView) {
    searchProductItemDit=[searchProductListArry objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"searchdit:%@",searchProductItemDit);
    cell.itemNameLbl.text= [searchProductItemDit objectForKey:@"name"];
    self.searchDisplayProduct.searchResultsTableView.separatorColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:200.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0];
} else {
    productItemDit=[productListArry objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"dit:%@",productItemDit);
    cell.itemNameLbl.text=[productItemDit objectForKey:@"name"];
}


cell.itemImg.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"profp.jpg"];

return cell;
```

}

Comment: Not getting your question.

Comment: Add some code you have tried for tableview

Comment: We need to see your code in `cellForRowAtIndex`

Comment: `loadNibNamed:` does not set the cellIdentifier and you don't set it manually. So no cell will be reused.

Comment: Check your numberOfRowsInSection: method. How many have to set there??  Does your table shows rows according to the number you set?

Comment: when i display table view.. it displaying correctly.my problem is When i scroll table view it is loading cells again and again same cells which is visible on table view. Please give solution for this.

Comment: if you are reusing the cell (static CellIdentifier) it will refresh the cell again and again while scrolling..

Comment: same result. Please check my edited question. I tried

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do like this,

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";
    ListOfProductsCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {

        Create your custom cell here....

        cell = [[[ListOfProductsCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

    }

  return cell;
}
```

Comment: if you ok with my answer. accept the answer. so that it will be useful for others..

Comment: I tried your code. When i run my app. The table view is displaying blank noting in that.

Comment: i just gave the idea for creating only when the cell is nil... after that you have to workout what ever you want to do....

Answer (score 1):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"IDENT"];
    if(cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"IDENT"];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

reuse tableviewcell like this

Comment: When i used this logic its not displaying table view

Comment: so there's some problem else in your code , not because the code above

Comment: I am displaying cell by custom. I created custom cell by Xib and all controllers are IBOutlet

Answer (score 0):

Note while the other answers are correct, if you're using iOS6 or later you should adopt the newer API that requires you to register your cell and it handles creation for you.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Tell the tableview what cell you're using
    [tableView registerClass:[MyCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"CellIdentifier"];

    // Or if you're using nibs tell the tableView which nib
    [tableView registerNib:YourNib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"CellIdentifier"];
}
```

If you're using Storyboards you won't need to register your cells, it has already done it for you.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Will not return nil ever if you've registered your class.
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure Cell

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: I can not able to solve this issue. By using your logic. Can you please tell me how to solve this.

Comment: Where it says configure cell, thats where you set your labels, images, or other cell properties.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayProduct.searchResultsTableView)
    {
        return [searchProductListArry count];
    }
    else
    {
        return [productListArry count];
    }
    return 0;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"cell %d",indexPath.row];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

        if (tableView == self.searchDisplayProduct.searchResultsTableView) {
            searchProductItemDit=[searchProductListArry objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            NSLog(@"searchdit:%@",searchProductItemDit);
            cell.itemNameLbl.text= [searchProductItemDit objectForKey:@"name"];
            self.searchDisplayProduct.searchResultsTableView.separatorColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:200.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0];
        } else {
            productItemDit=[productListArry objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            NSLog(@"dit:%@",productItemDit);
            cell.itemNameLbl.text=[productItemDit objectForKey:@"name"];
        }


        cell.itemImg.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"profp.jpg"];

    }
    // Configure the cell.
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using ARC than implement your cellForRowAtIndexPath Method as given below.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"YourIdentifier"];
    if(cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault  reuseIdentifier:@"YourIdentifier"];
    }
    return cell; }
```

If you are not using ARC than implement your cellForRowAtIndexPath Method as given below.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"YourIdentifier"];
    cell = nil;
    if(cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault     reuseIdentifier:@"YourIdentifier"] autorelease];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Your non ARC code will ALWAYS create because you are setting the cell to nil after loading. This will not reuse any cells.